# JTable Cell Color

Tags: java, swing, colors, jtable, tablecellrenderer

Can someone give me an example of how to get the background color of a particular cell in a JTable? I am unable to find an example of how to do this. Plenty of examples on getting the value in a cell, but not the background color of a cell.

Comment: after reading the answers I noticed that I misunderstood your question ;-) Even now, this still is a suboptimal question: without context and more details (f.i. why, what do you want to achieve, where/how exactly are you trying to get the color...) it is hard to answer correctly...

Answer (score 7):

It should be something like the following (fixed according to all comments):

**Important: use table.prepareRenderer(...) to let JTable do all work for you**

```
public Color getTableCellBackground(JTable table, int row, int col) {
    TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, col);
    Component component = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);
    return component.getBackground();
}
```

Full demo:

```
public class TableRenderDemo extends JPanel {

    public TableRenderDemo() {
        super(new GridLayout(1, 0));

        final JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(600, 200));
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyRenderer());

        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                int row = table.getSelectedRow();
                int col = table.getSelectedColumn();

                JOptionPane.showInternalMessageDialog(TableRenderDemo.this,
                        "Color: " + getTableCellBackground(table, row, col));

                System.out.println("Color: " + getTableCellBackground(table, row, col));
            }
        });

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    public Color getTableCellBackground(JTable table, int row, int col) {
        TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, col);
        Component component = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, col);    
        return component.getBackground();
    }

    class MyRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
            JTextField editor = new JTextField();
            if (value != null) {
                editor.setText(value.toString());
            }
            editor.setBackground((row % 2 == 0) ? Color.white : Color.BLUE);
            return editor;
        }
    }

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

        private String[] columnNames = {"First Name",
            "Last Name",
            "Sport",
            "# of Years",
            "Vegetarian"};
        private Object[][] data = {
            {"Kathy", "Smith",
                "Snowboarding", new Integer(5), new Boolean(false)},
            {"John", "Doe",
                "Rowing", new Integer(3), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Sue", "Black",
                "Knitting", new Integer(2), new Boolean(false)},
            {"Jane", "White",
                "Speed reading", new Integer(20), new Boolean(true)},
            {"Joe", "Brown",
                "Pool", new Integer(10), new Boolean(false)}
        };
        public final Object[] longValues = {"Jane", "Kathy",
            "None of the above",
            new Integer(20), Boolean.TRUE};

        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columnNames.length;
        }

        public int getRowCount() {
            return data.length;
        }

        public String getColumnName(int col) {
            return columnNames[col];
        }

        public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
            return data[row][col];
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableRenderDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        TableRenderDemo newContentPane = new TableRenderDemo();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); //content panes must be opaque
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this example, and I follow the logic, but for some reason I get 255,255,255 for each cell, but I have alternate row coloring, so I'm not sure what's going on here.

Comment: user1154644 did you searched, there are XxxCellRenderer and PrepareRenderer, and this code doesn't set any Color, nor to the Cell BackGround..., only skelleton of

Comment: How is the row highlighting applied?

Comment: Please find out updated answer with runnable demo inside. 
I'm getting 
Color: java.awt.Color[r=0,g=0,b=255] and 
Color: java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
respectively

Comment: this is wrong (as noticed by others already ;-) The _table_ is the instance that ultimately decides how a renderer should be configured, don't second-guess its decision by manually configuring it. Instead, let the table do it for you, by using its table.prepareRenderer(...) method

Comment: Fixed. Manual tableRenderer configuration is really unnecessary. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone give me an example of how to get the background color of a particular cell in a JTable? I am unable to find an example of how to do this.

- [TableCellRenderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tablecellrenderer) or for [Renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+swing+jtable+renderer),
- but everything is based on [JTable tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), expecially part of [Editors and Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) and [Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)
- plenty examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1040__JTable-Renderer-Editor.htm) and [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/pkg.html)

> Plenty of examples on getting the value in a cell, but not the background color of a cell.

- I can't resist, please on this forum or where
- I hope that help you ....

Answer (score 1):

To get the `JTable` color at cell `0, 0` you could get the background color of the cell component:

```
TableCellRenderer cellRenderer = table.getCellRenderer(0, 0);
Component rendererComponent = cellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, null, false, true, 0, 0);
Color cellColor = rendererComponent.getBackground();
```

Comment: Will not work if custom renderer with some tricky value-based logic is used or row is selected.

Comment: It will work if you pass the correct row/column to table.getCellRenderer

Comment: wrong ... this will not get you the color after configuration by the _table_, see [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12862835/203657)

Answer (score 0):

Use TableCellRenderer

```
jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable(6,6){
public Component prepareRenderer(
    TableCellRenderer renderer, int row, int column)
{

    Component c = super.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
    if(column==2 && row==4)
    {
       Color color= c.getBackground();// use setBackground to set color and get background to get background of a particular cell
       System.out.println("Color of row=0 and column=0 is "+color);

    }

    else
    {
        c.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        setShowGrid(true);
    }
    return c;

}
};
```

Comment: that doesn't answer the question (which isn't overly clear, concededly :-)

Comment: Did you notice that the System.out.println(); statment executes infinitely? I believe the method prepareRenderer is somehow called recursively. Is this expected behavior even if you use an object of the "pure" JTable class instead of your customized version?

Comment: @Prashan i answered it a long time back i do understand the answer is not perfect. I am not in touch with swing right now. Yes i know the answer is not perfect. i lost touch on swing and i now program on android.

Comment: I just avoided the recursion. REPLACE the setShowGrid(true) statement with the following code:
boolean oldHorizontalVal = this.showHorizontalLines;
showHorizontalLines = true;
firePropertyChange("showHorizontalLines", oldHorizontalVal, showHorizontalLines);
        
boolean oldVerticalVal = this.showVerticalLines;
showVerticalLines = true;
firePropertyChange("showVerticalLines", oldVerticalVal, showVerticalLines);